# Read a file in a specific line

Tags: lua

I have a txt file which stores data in the following format:

```
300
400
500
600
```

I was trying to read this file in a specific line, e.g. read(".txt",2) will return 500, I also try the following

```
cell.T = {}  -- temperatures, K (as a table)
filename = "input.txt"
fp = io.open( filename, "r" )
local n=0
for line in fp:lines() do
   n = n+1
   if n == index_number then
       cell.T[0]=line;
       break;
   end
end 
fp:close()
```

My index_number is 0 1 2 3 respectively, but what I get is 0 300 400 500

something elsewhere should be wrong, but I don't know how to figure it out, can anyone have a look at this file?

Comment: Why starts with `0`, not `1`?

Comment: How are the results different from what you expect? The results seem consistent with the code, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Why increment n at the beginning of the loop? If that's your intention, then you should actually start `index_number` at 1, as YuHao suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The `index_number` variable starts with `0`, but the code

```
local n=0
for line in fp:lines() do
   n = n+1
   if n == index_number then  -- this condition will never be met when n = 0
```

shows that `n` will never be `0` since it's incremented just before the check. Make the initialization like this

```
local n = -1
```

Or idiomatically, as indices start at `1` in Lua, you could change it to a post-increment

```
local n = 0
for line in fp:lines() do
    if n == index_number then
        -- do stuff
    end
    n = n + 1
end
```

Comment: Or rather start `index_number` at `1` and be more consistent with Lua semantics.

Comment: Agreed, I was playing safe due to your reply to Yu Hao's comment :)

Comment: Yeah, removed the comment ;)

Comment: Updated the answer with that option as well :P